# Cannot resolve symbol view. public void onClick(View view) does not work?

Tags: android, android-studio, onclick

I seem to have an issue with onClick(View view)

[Here's the screenshot of my android studio.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GA85h.png)

I have imported android.view.View. Here's my code

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
    totalTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.totalTextView);
    percentageTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.percentageTxt);
    numberTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.numberTxt);


    Button calcBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.calcBtn);
    calcBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.onClickListener()){
          @Override
          public void onClick(View view){
            float percentage = Float.parseFloat(percentageTxt.getText().toString());
            float dec = percentage / 100;
            float total = dec * Float.parseFloat(numberTxt.getText().toString());
            totalTextView.setText(Float.toString(total));
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You have an extra right parenthesis after `new View.onClickListener()`

Answer (score 0):

That's because you have an extra closing bracket, incorrect syntax:

```
calcButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()) { // extra closing bracket ')'
```

And change it to:

```
calcButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo with your anonymous function declaration. Also, there is a extra closing parenthesis.

```
calcBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.onClickListener())
```

should be

```
calcBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
```

After fixing the declaration and closing parenthesis, let us know if it is still not finding the View parameter.

Answer (score 0):

you must modify this sentence:

```
Button calcBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.calcBtn);
    calcBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.onClickListener())/* -->this parenthesis should not be closed here*/ { 
          @Override
          public void onClick(View view){
            float percentage = Float.parseFloat(percentageTxt.getText().toString());
            float dec = percentage / 100;
            float total = dec * Float.parseFloat(numberTxt.getText().toString());
            totalTextView.setText(Float.toString(total));
        }
    }
```

should be:

```
Button calcBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.calcBtn);
        calcBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.onClickListener() { 
              @Override
              public void onClick(View view){
                float percentage = Float.parseFloat(percentageTxt.getText().toString());
                float dec = percentage / 100;
                float total = dec * Float.parseFloat(numberTxt.getText().toString());
                totalTextView.setText(Float.toString(total));
            }
        });
```